# Is performance data for a lockfree stack at http://tinyurl.com/pzpyvb9 realistic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, benchmarking, lock-free

At the end of http://blog.memsql.com/common-pitfalls-in-writing-lock-free-algorithms/, David Stolp shows performance data for a lockfree stack showing that the lockfree version is slower than a sequential version protected by a mutex, even as contention increases. The results are interesting, but two things concern me:

- At best, "overall throughput" decreases and then levels out as the number of threads increases. Shouldn't overall throughput increase as the number of threads increases?
- In the final chart, the performance values for 1 thread range from about 35M to 55M. This seems like an awfully wide range for 1 thread (where there can't be any contention).

I've tried to find a way to contact the author about these issues, but I've had no success, so I'm turning to the SO community to see if the results seem realistic. Do they?

Comment: As I can see the mutex version si the slowest.

Comment: @GJ: From what I can tell, the mutex-based version is essentially the same (slow) speed as the "naive" lockfree version (per the final chart). It could be a bit slower, however, you're right. But that doesn't affect my questions about throughput as thread count increases or the wide range of throughput values for a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At best, "overall throughput" decreases and then levels out as the
>   number of threads increases. Shouldn't overall throughput increase as
>   the number of threads increases?

This is normaly! The stack is only one! Bottleneck is memory synchronisation between threads and not code execution. So if more threads fill the stack then more memory conflict should heppend (race conditions arise) so throughput decrease.

> In the final chart, the performance values for 1 thread range from
>   about 35M to 55M. This seems like an awfully wide range for 1 thread
>   (where there can't be any contention).

This test code is not realistic because it doing nothing more than poping and pushing the nodes in to the stack. So minimum difference at relatively short code can dramatically influence to the throughput.

If you check the code than you can see that the SpinLock version is very simple and could be faster than LockFree because is made with `test_and_set` atomic function which is normaly faster than atomic `CAS` (compare and swap) which is used at LockFree version.

**EDIT:**

At LockFree version is used `cmpxchg16b` which is 16 byte CAS at SpinLock is used only 8 byte  test_and_set function (implemented with `cmpxchg8b`) so the speed difference exist!

Comment: If the test code did some work between stack operations (e.g., do some work to prepare an object for the stack, then push it; after popping an element, do some work on it), we'd expect throughput to increase as the number of threads increased, right?  Also, am I correct that you downloaded the benchmark code and took a look at it?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Check code how is thread safe program stack made for LockFree and SpinLock. At  LockFree version is used `cmpxchg16b` which is 16 byte CAS at SpinLock is used only 8 byte CAS cmpxchg8b so the speed difference exist!

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, because it came in first. David Hammen's answer below is essentially the same, though it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

> At best, "overall throughput" decreases and then levels out as the number of threads increases. Shouldn't overall throughput increase as the number of threads increases?

Not necessarily, and definitely not in this case. Multithreading is beneficial if the threads of execution can run concurrently. It's better to make an application single threaded if the threads can never run concurrently or if almost all of the execution involves contention for one single resource.

This test was designed so that threads cannot run concurrently. Almost all of the code is contends for a single resource, a stack. This nominally bad design was intentionally used here so as to test the overhead expense of various concurrent execution schemes and to test how well the various schemes deal with contention.

> In the final chart, the performance values for 1 thread range from about 35M to 55M. This seems like an awfully wide range for 1 thread (where there can't be any contention).

Even without contention, there's a lot of overhead involved in locking and unlocking a mutex. There's a lot less overhead in compare-and-swap, even less in test-and-set. That pure overhead  is what is being tested when there is only one thread of execution.